# Don't know how to make two selects bridge together ad run a single query

Tags: oracle

I got the races to work then I added another query in addition to the same statement but when I ran the query and it only show student number, dob, gender and ethnicity but did not show another select with races add to.  I cannot figure it out.

```
select s.student_number,s.dob,s.gender,s.ethnicity
from students s, 
(select lastfirst,grade_level,
   max(case when rn = 1 then racecd end) race1, -- find 1st row
   max(case when rn = 2 then racecd end) race2, -- find 2nd row
   max(case when rn = 3 then racecd end) race3  -- find 3rd row
from
 (
   select
      s.lastfirst,s.grade_level,sr.racecd,
      row_number() -- one row per race, numbered 1,2,3,...
      over (partition by sr.studentid 
            order by sr.racecd) rn
   from students s
   join studentrace sr
     on s.id=sr.studentid
   where s.enroll_status=0
 )
 group by lastfirst,grade_level
 order by grade_level asc)
```

Comment: What are the 2 selects? What exactly are you trying your query to do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to reference the race fields in the initial `SELECT` statement (before the `FROM` clause) with an alias to the inner select.  I'm not quite sure what it is that you're trying to accomplish, but this is certainly more on track with what you desire.  Try this for starters

```
SELECT
    s.student_number,
    s.dob,
    s.gender,
    s.ethnicity,
    RaceTable.race1,
    RaceTable.race2, 
    RaceTable.race3
FROM students s INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        lastfirst, grade_level,
        max(case when rn = 1 then racecd end) race1, -- find 1st row
        max(case when rn = 2 then racecd end) race2, -- find 2nd row
        max(case when rn = 3 then racecd end) race3  -- find 3rd row
     FROM
         (SELECT
             st.lastfirst,st.grade_level,sr.racecd,
             st.student_number,st.dob,st.gender,st.ethnicity,
             row_number() -- one row per race, numbered 1,2,3,...
                 over (partition by sr.studentid 
                 order by sr.racecd) rn
          FROM students st
          JOIN studentrace sr
              ON st.id=sr.studentid
          WHERE st.enroll_status=0
         ) AS RTinner
     GROUP BY lastfirst,grade_level
  -- ORDER BY grade_level asc
    ) AS RaceTable
ON s.lastfirst=Racetable.lastfirst AND
   s.grade_level=Racetable.grade_level
```

Comment: note, I believe this will fail too because rn is not among the `GROUP BY` fields. also, the grade_level sort isn't doing anything for you because it's not being returned by the outer query either.